# Combinations matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

This code

```
 combinations = dec2base(0:power(2,N*M)-1,2) - '0'
```

generates all possible combinations of zeros and ones for a matrix of size N*M and stores all these combinations in a matrix called combinations. I need to know how it works , because i don't understand this code . Thank you

Comment: If you want to know what `dec2base` internally does, type `open dec2base` and see. Be careful not to modify anything. If what confuses you is some other part, please specify in your question

Comment: Thank you Luis, i know what dec2base () function do , it suppose to to converts an integer number to base d for example , but how this function is used to get all the possible combinations of and N*M matrix using this code ? In other words, what is this arguments  do and what is "-'0'" ?

Comment: No, this creates a `2^(M*N) x (M*N)` matrix. The `- '0'` converts the char output of `dec2base` to numeric.

Comment: Thank you beaker !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `M = 2`, `N = 3` as an example. Then `power(2,N*M)-1` is `63`, and `0:power(2,N*M)-1` is the vector `[0 1 2 ... 63]`.

`dec2base(..., 2)` converts those `64` numbers into base `2`, using chars `'0'` and `'1'` as "digits". Each result is in a row, left-padded with `'0'`'s if needed. So it gives the `64`×`6` char matrix

```
000000
000001
000010
....
111110
111111
```

To convert those chars into numbers, subtract `'0'`. That gives `0` for `'0'` and `1` for `'1'`, exploiting the fact that the ASCII codes for chars `'0'` and `'1'` are consecutive. So the final result is the numeric matrix

```
0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     1
0     0     0     0     1     0
....
1     1     1     1     1     0
1     1     1     1     1     1
```